# SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog errors when trying to render a Wiki Library Page

Tags: javascript, error, wiki, wiki-pages

I'm getting an error when trying to show a wiki library page using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog`. Other URLs work fine but not wiki library pages.

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({"url" : "http://site/wikitest"});
```

[image: error]

Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: Did you try looking up what the error is in the error logs?

Comment: where you placing the JS code?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Well for test I'm just using the developer console in IE. If I try `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({"url" : "http://site/[**anything else, like a list**]"});` it works but with a wiki library page it does not.

Comment: @DylanCristy: I don't have access to the SP farm. I was hoping it is a known issue or something?